# Swift: Keep playing sounds when the device is locked

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I'm using the following code to play a sound off a URL from the internet:

```
var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

...

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)

let url = trackFileName
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
audioPlayer.rate = 1.0;
player.play()
```

I'm trying to make sure it keeps playing in the background which is the reason why I'm using "AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()". When I try it out in the simulator by locking the screen, it keeps playing like it's supposed to. But if I play it in a device, the sounds shuts off as soon as the screen looks itself automatically or I lock it myself.

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html Did you add the background mode entitlement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

swift 2+ solution:

[image: audio]

```
do {
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch _ {
  return print("error")
}
```

Comment: Using `catch _` to print "error" is like not using error handling. For a better answer you could add a print of the caught error itself. :)

Comment: @HardikThakkar you can write code here catch _ {  // your error handling code }

Answer (score 1):

Open your app info.plist as Source code (to edit in text mode) and add the following just after dict:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I guess this just keeps my device from locking automatically? I did as you said and the autolock doesn't kick in. If I lock it manually the sound stops immediately.

Comment: The device should lock. UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true disables the lock screen.  The documentation about UIBackgroundModes is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

Comment: Well that's odd.. I tried it out and that's the only result I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong category, for `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` it's normal behavior "Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch".
Use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` instead.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should add background mode to your plist like this:[image]

Then you should use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback session. Like this:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
```

AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient does not work in background.