# How do I play an audio file from Swift File Manager?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio

I'm trying to play a file I downloaded from S3, after locating the file and passing the URL to the audio player, the audio file won't play/is missing.

This is the complete `fileURL`: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61F2FC20-4C62-4263-B147-0010805BC0FA/Documents/Dump%20Trucks.mp3`

Here is my code:

```
    func playAudio(){
    
    var soundClip: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    if let directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true).first{

        let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: directory).appendingPathComponent("Dump Trucks.mp3")

        print("The path is \(String(describing: path))")
        
        do {
            soundClip = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path!)
            soundClip?.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error: Audio File missing.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to play audio from device use `MPMediaItem`. it will retrive all audio from device.

Comment: one more thing i want to know you will get right path in this line ? //print("The path is \(String(describing: path))")

Comment: @RB's - Yes, it prints/returns the complete file URL indicated above.

Comment: `var soundClip: AVAudioPlayer?` change this with `var soundClip = AVAudioPlayer()`

Comment: You may check this solution for Swift 4+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149648/2125010

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your player is a local variable. Thus your method comes to an end and the player is destroyed before it ever has a chance to start playing! Declare it as an instance property instead.

So

```
func playAudio(){
    var soundClip: AVAudioPlayer?
```

Becomes

```
var soundClip: AVAudioPlayer?
func playAudio(){
```

This might not solve all your problems but if you don’t do it you certainly will never hear sound.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

final class MediaPlayer {
    static var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    class func play() {
        do {
            let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file_name", withExtension: "mp3")!
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: file)
            player.numberOfLoops = 0 // loop count, set -1 for infinite
            player.volume = 1
            player.prepareToPlay()

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player.play()
        } catch _ {
            print("catch")
        }
    }
}
```